# MathJax in CKEditor

Tags: css, plugins, ckeditor, font-size, mathjax

I am using Mathematical Formulas plugin for CKEditor 4 which employes MathJax. The problem is the font size for mathematical formulas is too small and I cannot find any ways to make it bigger.

I tried doing it via CSS

```
.MathJax, .MathJax_Display  {
    font-size: 1.4em!important;
}
```

It works for formulas in the page but not for the ones within CKEditor.

How am I supposed to adjust font-size of the formula in CKEditor?

Answer (score 0):

The native LaTeX formating is working with MathJax !

> LaTeX: Changing the Font Size
>   Latex provides 10 different font sizes. To change the size of a font use a > new font size parameter. The different font sizes are listed below.
>
> Font Sizes
>          \tiny
>          \scriptsize
>          \footnotesize
>          \small
>          \normalsize
>          \large
>          \Large
>          \LARGE
>          \huge
>          \Huge

https://engineering.purdue.edu/ECN/Support/KB/Docs/LaTeXChangingTheFont